# Trying to mark documents on the same page in selenium python

Tags: python, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

To do this i need to open a table then click on an image. then click on 2 different buttons and then do it over again.
Here's the loop:

---

```
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value= '2350321']")
elem1.click()
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("positive")
elem2.click()

button1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul/li[7]/a")
button1.click()
el = driver.find_element_by_id("logo")
button2 = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

for i in range(4):
    driver.implicitly_wait(5) 

    button2.move_to_element_with_offset(driver.find_element_by_id("logo"), 642, 147).click().click().perform()
    driver.implicitly_wait(15)

    button3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[8]/a/img")
    button3.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)

    button4 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("positive")
    button4.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    button5 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("positive")
    button5.click()
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-3)")
    time.sleep(4)
```

I keep getting "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" whenever the loop starts the second time (when `button2.move_to_element_with_offset(driver.find_element_by_id("logo"), 642, 147).click().click().perform()` is performed)

Comment: seems to be you the `button2` element reference is refreshed (you might clicked on something or page might loaded content after you got `button2` in your code). Please replace `button2` with the `driver.findelement` or get `button2` as part of your for loop first step.

Comment: sorry i havent posted the full thing.

Comment: im testing right now, but your comment seemed to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below snippet.

Imports needed

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
```

Add the below 2 methods under imports or if you are comfortable with python please place them in a separate library/file.

```
def highlight(web_driver, element):
    web_driver = element._parent
    original_style = element.get_attribute('style')
    web_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", element,
                              "background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;")
    time.sleep(.3)
    web_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", element, original_style)


def element_click(web_driver,xpath, max_time_out=30):
    wait = WebDriverWait(web_driver, max_time_out)
    ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,xpath)))
    highlight(webdriver, ele)
    ele.click()
```

Now follows your script using explicit wait

```
element_click(driver, "//input[@value= '2350321']")
element_click(driver, "//*[@class='positive']")
element_click(driver, "//ul/li[7]/a")

for i in range(4):
    element_click(driver, "//*[@id='logo']") # check if it works if not then you can use the below line and comment this line.
    # driver.execute_script("arugments[0].click()",driver.find_element_by_id("logo"))
    element_click(driver, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[8]/a/img")
    element_click(driver, "//*[@class='positive']")
    element_click(driver, "//*[@class='positive']")
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-3)")
    time.sleep(4)
```